# How to add Marker on map for every 30 sec using ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new in Android programming. I want to plot marker on google map. For this example I just used hard coded lat, lng and plot marker for every 30 sec. I used ScheduledExecutorService for this application. But the marker is not visible on my map. At logcat the log is visible. Can somebody help me or point me to the right solution. Below is my code snippet.

```
    scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {

          Log.d("scheduleTaskExecutor log : ","run every 10 seconds");

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(defaultLatLng)
        .title("T69")
        .snippet("Your're here"));


      }
    }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

TQ.

Answer (score 0):

Ok..I got the solution. Just used runOnUiThread. Example as below:

```
    scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          Log.d("RUN RUN RUN ","run every 10 seconds");
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              // update your UI component here.
           try {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(defaultLatLng)
                .title("T69));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("MAP" ,e.getMessage());
            }
            }
          });
        }
    }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```